# Open file in Team Explorer (Git Integration) without diff

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

Since a while back, double clicking a file in the change tree in Team Explorer opens the file in diff mode. I find this very annoying since I use the change tree for easy navigation among the files I am currently working on.

Double clicking used to simply open the file. If i want to diff it, I have a shortcut for that.

It seems reasonable that there should be a setting for this, but I can't find it.

Having a separate shortcut for simply opening it, or right click -> select open is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Actually solved this my self!

In the top right corner of the change list is a [...] button. It has "Open file as default action"

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you discovered the setting in the [...] options menu.  That allows you to set the default (diff or open), and then you can use the shift key (shift+dblclick, shift+enter) to perform the non-default operation.

Hope this helps.